# Adding div elements in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I am building a page preloader with ReactJS. The Codepen snippet I am using is written in HTML and I need help converting it into HTML ready for React.

Part of the snippet

```html
<div class="socket">
  <div class="gel center-gel">
    <div class="hex-brick h1"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h2"></div>
    <div class="hex-brick h3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Conversion to React

```html
<div className={s.socket}>
  <div className={s.gel s.center-gel}>
    <div className={s.hex_brick s.h1}></div>
    <div className={s.hex_brick s.h2}></div>
    <div className={s.hex_brick s.h3}></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have replaced hyphens with underscores, used curly brackets instead of quotes, and added Name to the class. However, I don't know how to add the second div modifier (for example in div gel there is element center-gel). When a second element is added to a React div, it fails to compile.

React does not allow these second div elements. After testing, my loading animation does not look correct if I separate out the elements, the structure needs to stay the same.

[Snippet Used](https://codepen.io/aslan11/pen/IxLDJ)

Comment: What is `s`? Everything within the curly brackets is evaluated, not a simple replacement.

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit? I would be helpful knowing what `s` is. Are you using css-modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write JSX code in React you are actually writing JavaScript code. Let's say you put those expression into a variable like so:

```
var styles = s.gel s.center-gel;
```

It just doesn't make any sense in JS. You need to write a valid expression like this:

```
var styles = [s.gel, s['center-gel']].join(' ');
```

Keeping that in mind, your code should work this way:

```
<div className={s.socket}>
    <div className={[s.gel, s['center-gel']].join(' ')}>
        <div className={[s.hex_brick, s.h1].join(' ')}></div>
        <div className={[s.hex_brick, s.h2].join(' ')}></div>
        <div className={[s.hex_brick, s.h3].join(' ')}></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would this work for three elements? say <div class="gel c2 r1">